# Consolidating panels in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I split a panel into multiple panels and have multiple files open, how do I return to one panel and have those files consolidate into one? In Sublime Text, they call it columns and you can split the panel into multiple columns with `cmd + option + 2` for two panels. If you want three, just press `3` instead of `2`.

Is there any functionality (native or with an extension) like that in VS Code? I know that I can split a panel as many times but there is no way to consolidate. AND there is no way to dictate how many panels I want to split into in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [join editors of two groups](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_11#_join-editors-of-two-groups) command. By default there isn't a key binding for this but you can easily [set one up](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) yourself.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to Stack Overflow.  If this answer, or any other, has solved your issue consider marking it accepted.